# Is it possible to group/join meshes by material?

Tags: mesh, materials

I have a model generated from ifc. However throughout the generation process, it's separated all the meshes into individual ones. Is it possible to merge them by materials? Like merge all meshes that use material ifcWallStandardCase for example.

Cheers :)

[image]

Comment: You can select one object. and tthen go to the select menu on the top left, and go to select similar>material. It will selct all the objects with the same material, and then just hit Ctrl+J to join. It will be one mesh in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join all the mesh objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> (or type in `Join` after pressing  <kbd>F3</kbd>)

[image]

Then separate them by material with  <kbd>P</kbd> while in *Edit Mode*.
[image]

That should give you the result you seek.

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Absolute Lifesaver, Thanks!